# one issue about the parameter in php function

Tags: php

```
<?php
function baz(ReflectionFunction $a, $b = 1, $c = null) { }
$reflect = new ReflectionFunction("baz");
echo $reflect;
...
?>
```

Question:
what does this mean: `ReflectionFunction $a`? is this equal to: `$a = new ReflectionFunction()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function baz(ReflectionFunction $a, ...
```

is a so called [`type hint`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php). This allows the PHP interpreter to check the arguments type at runtime

If you would pass a value which's type is not `ReflectionFunction` PHP would throw a fatal error. This is very helpful to stabelize your code and help from many programming errors which are caused and overseen because of the loose-typing system of PHP

You can see it in affect if you would pass a string for instance:

```
baz('my_function');
```

what will give you:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to baz() must be an instance of ReflectionFunction, string given, called in /tmp/peerindex-api-consumer/a.php on line 5 and defined in /tmp/peerindex-api-consumer/a.php on line 3